# Getting role id and current user id

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, model-view-controller

I am trying to authenticate various roles such as buyers and sellers.

I am trying to get the roleid and current userid, so as to check if the person is authenticated to view certain page.

```
var result = DBContext.UserRoles
            .Where(ur => ur.Role.RoleName == "Seller")
             .Select(ur => new {ur.UserID });
```

I am not sure how do i return the result.

the code is suppose to get the result and if the result is true  then the user will be able to view the pages according.

Comment: `.Any(ur => ur.Role.RoleName == "Seller" && ur.UserID == userId)`? Hard to tell without knowing how your page views are authorized.

Comment: var result = Login.UserRoles
                        .Any(ur => ur.Role.RoleName == "Seller" && ur.UserID ==    
                        ur.UserID) ;
                                                                                                      
 so if result is true, listing page will be returned. If result is false, we will have to check if rolename == "buyer" . On top of that there will be a unauthorized page,if a buyer wants to view a seller page.